# Socket.io: correct way for the server to reconnect the client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm building MEAN application with socket.io. When page is just loaded, socket connection is established and kept live while user navigates to various pages, thanks to single-page nature of the app.

The user information is available in my socket connection thanks to [passport.socketio](https://github.com/jfromaniello/passport.socketio).

However, when user logs in or out, I want the connection to be re-initialized, since otherwise socket will contain obsolete data about the user. Currently, I tried to implement it in this way: when user logs in / out, server disconnects this particular client's socket by calling `socket.disconnect();`.

On the client side, I listen for `disconnect` event, and try to re-establish the connection, like this:

```
  _socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
     _socket.connect();
  });
```

Ok, now, when user logs out or in, server disconnects the client, this client connects back, and user information in the socket is up-to date. So far, so good.

But, consider different case when connection is broken: server is restarted. Previously, it "just worked": when I stop my server, connection is broken, but when I start server again, connection is automatically re-established. But after I've added my `_socket.connect();` call, it doesn't work anymore: connection is still down until I refresh the page in the browser.

I've checked that when server calls `disconnect();`, the `reason` given to `disconnect` handler is: `io server disconnect`. And when server stops, the reason is: `transport close`.

Ok, then, I've implemented my disconnect handler as follows:

```
  _socket.on('disconnect', function(reason) {
     if (reason === 'transport close'){
        // don't do anything special
     } else {
        _socket.connect();
     }
  });
```

Now it works. But, all of it seems as absolute dirty hack. At the very least, the `reason`s given (`io server disconnect` and `transport close`) seem to be just human-readable strings, so they might change in the future, and this will cause my code to stop working. And, well, there should be better way to do this; I must miss something essential, but unfortunately I can't find any good documentation on socket.io.

So, the question is: what is the correct way for the server to reconnect some particular client?

Additionally, if you have any recommendations on resources to learn about socket.io, I'd appreciate it very much as well.

Comment: Having the same problem right now, did you end up fixing the problem?

Comment: I think no, sorry. :( Actually the project I've been working on back then is dead, but I recall that I had to live with this dirty hack.

Comment: Thank you, though not the nicest solution, it works :)